# How to use constrains property for Input in UI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to restrict the user to enter only numbers.
Maybe I can do this using regular expression but I don't know the exact syntax.
I don't want decimal or special characters.

```
<Input type="Number"
value="{
    type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Number',
    constraints : {
        minLength: 1,
        maxLength: 15,
        validate: ...
    }
}" />
```

Comment: when you specify     <Input type="Number" /> it brings up numeric keypad on device.

Answer (score 7):

The sap.ui.model.type.Number doesn't exist, but [Integer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.Integer.html) and [Float](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.Float.html) do.

```
<Input 
    type="Number"
    value="{
        path: '/number',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer',
        formatOptions: {
            groupingEnabled: false,
            groupingSeparator: ',',
            decimalSeparator: '.'
        },
        constraints : {
            minimum: '0',
            maximum: '99'
        }
}" />
```

I think the integer type is just what you need. Only integer numbers are valid and by default there is no grouping, decimals or other characters. You could use SAPUI5's [error handling capabilities](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b8c4e534cdb440e9a5bbff86f9572bd6.html) to alert the user if an invalid entry has been entered.

If you want to prevent invalid characters to be even entered, you could use the masked input control. E.g.:

```
<MaskInput 
    mask = "999999" 
    placeholderSymbol = "_" 
    placeholder = "Enter a six digit number"/>
```

However, personally I find them a bit ugly for regular number. The mask input control is actually meant for input values that follow a certain pattern such as credit card number or postal codes.

Answer (score 4):

The very `<Input type="Number"` accepts nothing but numbers however if you still want to implement your own validation you can do as follow the below regex used to consider only numbers:

Define `regex`:

```
regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
```

Add `liveChange` to your input

```
    liveChange: function(oEvent){
        if(oEvent.getParameter("liveValue") === "" 
                  || !oEvent.getParameter("liveValue").match(regex)){
                this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
   }
    else{
               this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict the input type to `Number`, no (special) characters are allowed to enter into the input field. However, number related characters (`.,-`) are allowed. To get rid of it, you can set the data type of your property binding to `sap.ui.model.type.Integer`. You can also set the `minLength`, `maxLength` etc. constraints. If user types in `2.1`, a validation error will be thrown and the input field value state will be set to Error.

```
<Input type="Number"
   value="{
      type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer',
      constraints : {
          minLength: 1,
          maxLength: 15
   }
}" />
```

[Documentation of the Integer type.](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f3145e6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

[Here is an other example for field validation with MessageManager](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b8c4e534cdb440e9a5bbff86f9572bd6.html)